# Is there a way to improve the efficiency of this code? I am trying to generate xml files for each file present in the folder

Tags: python

I have a csv sheet where data is arranged in about 12 cols. I also happen to have about 30k images in a folder (these file names are reflected in the csv). I am trying to generate a xml file for each of the jpg image in the folder. The code works, but it takes forever:

```
import glob
import lxml.builder
from lxml import etree
import csv
import os

list_files = (glob.glob("D:/Data/tiger/*"))
for x in list_files:
    f = open('D:/Data/tiger/tiger.csv')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_f:
        print(row[0])
        if row[0] == x:
            print(list_files[i])
            i += 1
            print("Yes, it matches")
            [code to generate xml]
            tree = E.ElementTree(xml_file)
            filename = row[2] + fn + ".xml"
            with open(filename,'w') as f: ## Write document to file

f.write(etree.tostring(xml_file,pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))
            break
```

Is there a way to reduce the runtime of the code? It seems like it can take forever since I am looping through two incredibly long lists.

Comment: I think your question will get answered better [on Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What is *forever*? Please qualify this ambiguous term with specific timings. And we need to see `[code to generate xml]`. Are you embedding the binary data of image into XML or a file path? And show us sample of csv data. You could update it with picture paths and run one loop.